Selecting interpreter in VS Code does not activate environment
I am working with a conda environment that contains multiple packages, and I am trying to debug a Python script that calls those packages via shell commands. While selecting interpreter via VS Code uses that environment's packages, it does not allow me to use the packages installed directly via conda.
Take this code example:
    import os
    import sys
    print(f'python: {sys.executable}')
    print(f"env: {os.environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV']}")
    print('Trying trimmomatic:')
    print(os.system('trimmomatic'))
    print('\nTrying trimmomatic ater explicit conda activate:')
    print(os.system('source ~/.bashrc; conda activate myenv; trimmomatic'))

I have an environment myenv that has the tool trimmomatic installed. You can see from the sys.executable (and from the bottom right corner of VS Code) that the interpreter is selected. However, in the second line, you can see that the conda environment is not activated, and instead base is the active environment. As a result, I cannot use the tool unless I activate the environment in conda explicitly. So this is the output I get:
python: /path/to/envs/myenv/bin/python
env: base
Trying trimmomatic:
sh: line 1: trimmomatic: command not found
32512

Trying trimmomatic after explicit conda activate:
Usage: 
       PE [-version] [-threads <threads>] [-phred33|-phred64] [-trimlog <trimLogFile>] [-summary <statsSummaryFile>] [-quiet] [-validatePairs] [-basein <inputBase> | <inputFile1> <inputFile2>] [-baseout <outputBase> | <outputFile1P> <outputFile1U> <outputFile2P> <outputFile2U>] <trimmer1>...
   or: 
   SE [-version] [-threads <threads>] [-phred33|-phred64] [-trimlog <trimLogFile>] [-summary <statsSummaryFile>] [-quiet] <inputFile> <outputFile> <trimmer1>...
   or: 
   -version
256

How can I get VS Code to really activate the environment?

This could potentially be a manifestation of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78886126/7483211 - can you try setting "python.locator": "js", in your user settings?

Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately it didn't help solve it.

If you open a new terminal with the Terminal: Create New Terminal command, VS Code will automatically activate the selected environment.
If you want to continue using the current terminal, you can try executing any python script after selecting the python interpreter, which will automatically activate the environment and run the file in the new environment.
You could also command active condaName in your terminal to active the environment manually.

Creating a new terminal does activate the selected environment (weirdly though - I see (myenv) (base) before the prompt instead of just (myenv). However when I debug a new terminal opens and that one has again base activated. I can activate manually in that one and it works.
